# Automatically generate a form based on a channel field set?

Tags: safecracker, custom-fields, forms

I have a field set that's going to be growing over time. Users will be filling out forms on signup that represent this field set.

Is there a way to automatically generate this sign up form based on the field set, instead of manually updating the form when I update the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using the {custom_fields} loop of SafeCraker. In case, you wouldn't like to show some specific custom fields, don't populate them using if condition.

Like:

```
{custom_fields}

{if field_name != "not_show_field_1" AND field_name != "not_show_field_2"}

[Custom field options]

{/if}

{/custom_fields}
```

Take a reference from http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#custom-fields

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Hm, I've generally avoided the custom fields loop in the past because it has some real weaknesses, but you're right, it may be my answer here.